# Print every character in a string before a specific character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
phrase='!_#@%'
pun=''
string='dj_khaled'
for item in string:
    if item not in phrase:
       pun=pun+item
print(pun)
```

My problem is that, the outpout i get is djkhaled instead it should be dj, So basically, i want to include every character before some symbol occurs. The string is alphanumberic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop adds to `pun` whenever a character is not in `phrase`, instead you should check if a character *is in* phrase and `break` accordingly. Until then you continuously add characters to `pun`:

```
for item in string:
    if item in phrase:
        break
    pun += item
```

When executed it now prints out correctly `"dj"`.

You could also consider `takewhile` from `itertools` if the previous approach doesn't suffice:

```
>>> "".join(takewhile(lambda x: x not in phrase, string))
"dj"
```

Yet another approach that doesn't use a `break`(?) could be by using a boolean flag that indicates whether the value in the `phrase` was seen, you can then act on that when deciding if you should add to `pun` or not:

```
phrase='!_#@%'
pun=''
string='dj!khaled'
seen = False
for item in string:
    if item in phrase:
       seen = True
    if not seen:
        pun += item
print(pun)
```

Comment: what if i have multiple symbols like !-#

Comment: then you can use `if any(item == i for i in phrase)` to evaluate before `break`ing.

Comment: is there another way for doing this i dont like using break

Comment: What's wrong with using `break`? It's the standard way  to break execution when needed. @CAVS

Comment: Right, that doesn't make much sense but maybe he's up to something. Either way the other approach you could use is with a boolean flag that dictates whether you've seen the item in `phrase`; take a look at my update.

Comment: yet another way is to put the first example in a function and instead of break use `return pun`. Perhaps that is the desire of prof?

Comment: Maybe @Copperfield? I thought that if `break` was a no-op, so would `return`ing.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard what if i had _dj_khaled? is there a way i can ignore the first occur of _

Comment: well @JimFasarakis-Hilliard the OP have not said what are his/her the restriction other than `break`, and if the prof already teaches about function then that should not be a problem and perhaps the trick is realize this by forbidden break.

Comment: @Copperfield the reason why i dont wanna use break is because my prof will be doing test casing and i feel break might screw up my code

Comment: @CAVS I don't see how using the adequate tool that is designed specially for this purpose may screw you up, more soo if it is a standard feature of the language that is always available. So I take that your prof did not really forbid `break`? and you just have some fear for it? if the latter, don't fear it, as long as you use your tools in the correct way they would make your job more easy, and `break` is easy to master

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more easily using indexing with the `index` method:

```
pun = string[:string.index(phrase)]
print(pun)
```

if we have multiple 'phrases', and some may not be in the string:

```
phrase=['_','j','z']

pun = string[:min([string.index(i) for i in phrase if i in string])]
print(pun)
```

Comment: It will throw an error if the phrase is not a substring of the string. A simple `if phrase in string:` check would be enough to 'fix' it.

Answer (score 0):

yet another way is doing it old style with a `while` loop

```
forbidden ='!_#@%'
string='dj_khaled'
result =""
i = 0
while i<len(string) and string[i] not in forbidden:
    result = result + string[i]
    i = i+1
print( result )
```

but this is more easy to screw up, but is functionally the same as using `break` in the first example of Jin.

and the function version that I mention in the comments

```
def myfun(string):
    forbidden ='!_#@%'
    result = ""
    for c in string:
        if c in forbidden:
            return result  #normally here you put the break
        result = result + c
    return result

print( myfun('dj_khaled') )
```